# ADO _Recordset Object: strange invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, constructor, ado

I'm simply creating a Class that holds a _RecordsetPtr as a member..
This is what I have so far:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    _RecordsetPtr m_RecPtr;
}

MyClass::MyClass() {
    m_RecPtr = NULL;
    m_RecPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
    m_RecPtr->CursorType = adOpenStatic;                 // ERROR!
    m_RecPtr->CursorLocation = adUseClient;         
    m_RecPtr->Sort = "";
}



int main() {
    MyClass c;             //ERROR!
}
```

The error occurs in the main method where the default constructor of MyClass is called..

I'm just instantiating the m_RecPtr object,, but when I try setting its cursor location,

It strangely gives me an "Invalid Pointer" error...

I've looked at ADO Documentation ([Link!!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675084(v=vs.85).aspx)), and it seems like I'm instantiating the _RecordsetPtr object correctly...

This is how it's done in the documentation I linked (Which is EXACTLY the same as what I'm doing!!):

```
_RecordsetPtr pRstAuthors = NULL;
pRstAuthors.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset))
pRstAuthors->CursorType = adOpenStatic;
pRstAuthors->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
...
```

So what's wrong with my constructor??

Why does doing the same thing not work when it's done in a Class constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call CoInitialize(NULL) to initialize the COM environment before using COM object, also, you should call CoUninitialize() to free COM at the end.

In the example you gave, the main function call the both functions.